# AWS Cognito Facebook and Google Plus User login credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Folks, am working on, AWS Cognito Facebook and Google Plus login for my iOS app. I can able to SignIn with both FB and G+ credentials and I got Identity ID as a response. Is there any way to get user credentials such as username, email and mobile number. I have tried with user pools but I got null value when I use [self.pool currentUser].username.

I also tried below,

```
    AWSCognito *syncClient = [AWSCognito defaultCognito];
    AWSCognitoDataset *dataset = [syncClient openOrCreateDataset:@"myDataSet"];
    NSString *userName = [dataset stringForKey:@"name"];
```

But still getting null as userName. If possible can you please let me know the possible way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to request for "profile" or other scopes in order to get that.

I recently created a related framework and it has an example of retrieving the user profile information. https://github.com/Thywis/MultiAccountOauth